# Changed SSH port, do I need to open the port using iptables?

Tags: ssh, centos

**UPDATE**

As Khaled suggested, i changed my netstat command

```
netstat -lnp | grep 3899
tcp        0      0 :::3899           :::*              LISTEN      10333/sshd
```

So shouldn't it be listening?

---

I changed my ssh port on my centos 5.5 box to 3899. But I can't seem to login remotely to it. I have done this before but the last time, I didn't need to make any other changes to make it work.

```
iptables -L | grep 3899
[empty response]

iptables -L | grep 22
[empty response]

iptables -L | grep ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere       anywhere       state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you probably need to adjust your firewall rules.  To see your current rules:

```
iptables -nvL
```

If you see a bunch of ACCEPT rules and a REJECT rule at the end, that means your host is blocking all incoming connections except the specified ones.

I *think* you can use the `system-config-securitylevel` menu-based tool to open custom ports.  Run that program in a terminal and choose the 'customize' button.  Add `3899:tcp` to the *other ports* list and save your changes.  I'm not sure if system-config-securitylevel takes port numbers instead of service names.  If specifying the port number in that tool doesn't work, you can try adding your custom 'myssh' service name to `/etc/services` and then using that name in system-config-securitylevel.

You can run

```
nmap -sS -v server.example.com
```

from an outside machine to scan your system to determine which ports are open.

Another way to make this change is to hand edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, and copy the existing ssh entry to another entry right below it, but change the port from ssh to 3899.  Note that it's easy to screw up your firewall config by hand-editing the iptables file, so be very cautious if you go this route.  After you make changes, reboot the machine, or run `/etc/init.d/iptables restart` to load your changes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I never new about `system-config-securitylevel`. I changed the rule for 22 to 3899 in /etc/sysconfig/iptables and it works perfectly now. If your answer wasn't so detailed and generally helpful, I would have ignored it seeing that you asked me to reboot a linux machine =D

Comment: 'reboot the machine' is the simple answer, but note you can also use `iptables -I chain num` to insert rules in your running iptables without even flushing the existing rules.  That's the maximum uptime solution, no reboot required. :)

Answer (score 2):

run this and it should add entry to allow connecting to port 3899

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3899 -j ACCEPT`

your post does not show what is default policy for INPUT chain, or what other rules are.

copy paste here output of

`iptables-save` and `netstat -nlp` 
then we will know all the details needed to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably yes -- If your iptables rules are active the destination port SSH (`dpt:ssh`) rule only covers port 22 -- the standard SSH port as assigned by IANA & listed in /etc/services.

You will need to change that rule to allow traffic to port 3899 (or whatever your new SSH port is) - On CentOS I believe the ipables rules are located in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure that SSH deamon is really listening on the new port using `netstat -lnp | grep 3899`.
2. Also, you need to check your firewall settings. Allow the new port to pass through.

If you are getting a connection refused error, then you have a problem in point 1. If you are getting a connection timeout error, then you have a problem in point 2.

Comment: Update answer with result

Answer (score 0):

CentOS wil use port 22 regardless of the use of dpt:ssh
You should manually open port 3899

You can do this by running this command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3899 -j ACCEPT
```